# Parallel pausing and resuming?

Tags: gpg, cpu-usage, gnu-parallel

I have a pretty strange thing I'm seeing as I run 8 GPG encryption jobs with GNU parallel:

[image]

The command I've run is this:

```
find . -type f -not -iname "*.gpg" | sort |parallel --gnu -j 8 --workdir "$PWD" '
    echo "Encrypting {}..." ; 
    gpg --encrypt --recipient "me@mail.com" "{}"
'
```

Why do the jobs seem to start and stop and start and stop rather than simply occupying all of the CPU time?

Answer (score 3):

GPG needs some random bytes to encrypt. If you run out of entropy in the pool, that will cause GPG to pause.

`--quick-random` will use low quality random numbers, making the encryption insecure (and therefore useless, so use it only to test whether this is the problem, not in production), but will not run out. If using `--quick-random` will not pause, then this is the reason for your problem.

Comment: This might be the problem. I'm running 8 of them in parallel, it really could be that it's running out of entropy. I'll try this out.

Comment: That's a good hypothesis. However @NaftuliTzviKay **do not use `--quick-random`**: it is for testing only, it is not secure. (I don't what algorithm gpg uses by default, depending on exactly what it does a bad RNG could mean that the ciphertext is trivial to decrypt.) The right solution would be to use `/dev/urandom` instead of `/dev/random` (this is secure except on a freshly installed system). Unfortunately gpg does not have an option to use `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting, I thought `--quick-random` would use `/dev/urandom`. Guess I'm not using it, then :)

Answer (score 3):

As [Ole Tange wrote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/105085/15241), gpg needs random data from `/dev/random`, which can slow down quite quickly if there is not enough entropy.

A good solution to this problem is [haveged](http://www.issihosts.com/haveged/index.html). If necessary, it provides new entropy to the kernel (and therefore to /dev/random).

Answer (score 1):

[Ole Tange's hypothesis](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105059/parallel-pausing-and-resuming/105085#105085) that Gpg is blocking on a read to `/dev/random` is a good one. You can confirm it by looking at one of the gpg processes while it's blocked and checking what it's blocked on:

```
lsof -p1234
strace -s9999 -tt -p1234
```

(where 1234 is the PID of the gpg process). If you see something like this

```
…
gpg     1234 naftuli   4r   CHR    1,8      0t0       0 /dev/random
…
read(4, …
```

then this is the problem.

Gpg has no option to use `/dev/urandom` instead of `/dev/random`. The difference between those two devices is that `/dev/urandom` never blocks (even in the rare circumstances when it should) whereas `/dev/random` often blocks (even in the common cases where it shouldn't). For the long story, read [Is a rand from /dev/urandom secure for a login key?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key/3939#3939)

A quick workaround would be to make a copy of the gpg binary, replace `/dev/random` by `/tmp/random` (or anything else with the same length, which unfortunately excludes `/dev/urandom`), and create a symbolic link `/tmp/random -> /dev/urandom`.

Comment: IMHO a better solution would be to use entropy feeders like `clrngd` or `rng-tools`. Even better would be to use a hardware entropy feeder.

Comment: @EliasProbst That's overkill. Entropy decays away at a geological pace (or a bit slower, in fact, with typical values). Once you have entropy, it stays had, and `/dev/urandom` is perfectly secure.

Comment: I _could_ always just buy a Geiger counter and go __all the way...__ However, `/dev/urandom` should be secure enough for normal usage.

Answer (score 0):

#### Swap, I/O?

What does 1 of the threads look like? My first instinct is that the system is waiting for some resource to become available, perhaps disks? swap?

#### Built-in delay?

The other thought is that `gpg` may have some delays built in for no other reason than to add to the expense of creating keys, and so the delays are causing your lull in CPU usage.

These would be a form of a NOOP, where the key generation algorithm waits idle for some period of time to pass before proceeding.

Also you can gain insight into what's going on by running 1 of the `gpg` processes using `strace` to see what system calls are being made.

#### Example

```
$ strace gpg --encrypt --recipient "me@mail.com" "..."
```

#### Buffer?

The other thing I would be suspicious of is buffering. Perhaps there is a buffer  in your pipeline that is being exhausted faster than can be replenished, so the `gpg` processes are being starved for work to do.

You could use a tool such as `pv` to ferret out this issue by putting it after the output from `find`.

#### Example

```
$ find .... | sort | pv | ...
```

I'd look at these switches:

```
   -a, --average-rate
          Turn the average rate counter on.  This will display the average 
          rate of data transfer so far.

   -b, --bytes
          Turn the total byte counter on.  This will display the total 
          amount of data transferred so far.
```