# gpg key generation on Tails live cd - why so quick?

Tags: gpg, random

I just used `gpg2 --gen-key` to generate a 2048 bit RSA key pair on an OS running on a live cd (Tails). This happened much faster than I expected. When I have done this before on a regular machine it takes a bit of time, and I typically need to wait and briefly do something else. I think that is because it takes some time to generate the required amount of randomness.

Does a live cd have some unusual process such that the boot process generates more than normal randomness? Or is it possible that it is using `/dev/urandom` instead? As far as I was aware, gpg uses `/dev/random` which is why it can take some time to generate keys.

Comment: I have done this using Ubuntu Privacy Remix, both are based on Debian and on UPR this did not speed up at all. (I got the impression it was even slower because less processes were running than normally on my desktop). I have described the process for generating keys for a smartcard while off-line [here](http://anthon.home.xs4all.nl/rants/2014/setting_up_an_openpgp_smartcard_with_gnupg/)

Comment: yes, if anything that's what I would have expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer: Tails comes packaged with the random number generator 'haveged'. 
http://www.reddit.com/r/tails/comments/2oxr7n/how_does_tails_generate_gpg_keys_so_fast/

I have edited the question's title to reflect that this is particular to Tails.

Here is some discussion of whether the HAVEGED algorithm is any good: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8083/quality-of-randomness-on-a-linux-system-with-haveged

The conservative approach taken by gpg in using `/dev/random` may be overkill in many situations, compared with using `/dev/urandom` but from the specific point of view of a live CD environment used for gpg key generation without time constraints, using haveged seems unnecessary.

So it seems to me the simplest solution is to kill the haveged process in Tails, wait for /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail to deplete, and then let gpg just do what it normally does.

Answer (score 1):

Entropy (“randomness”) is accumulated in the kernel. If the kernel has accumulated enough entropy before GPG starts, GPG benefits from it immediately.

Linux's handling of entropy is somewhat broken. Linux has two devices: `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom`. `/dev/random` blocks for as long as it takes to accumulate sufficient entropy. `/dev/urandom` always returns data without blocking. In principle, this would be a good thing. The problem is that Linux's entropy calculation is extremely conservative: it assumes that entropy gets used up, which is only true in a highly theoretical sense. So `/dev/random` tends to block when it shouldn't.

On a normal system, you should [just use `/dev/urandom`](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key/3939#3939) — though [some software, including gpg, doesn't give you a choice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105059/parallel-pausing-and-resuming/105100#105100). However, on a live CD, immediately after boot, there may be very little entropy, unless your computer has a hardware RNG (such as the [RdRand instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RdRand) on recent Intel processors) and Linux supports it. So in this case you do need to use `/dev/random` and wait if necessary. User interaction (e.g. moving the mouse) will contribute to this entropy.

See also [Adding "random number entropy" for GPG keys?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136874/adding-random-number-entropy-for-gpg-keys/136879#136879) and [Can you explain the entropy estimate used in random.c](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129265/can-you-explain-the-entropy-estimate-used-in-random-c)

Again, you don't need to worry: GPG+Linux is very conservative when it comes to estimating entropy. If GPG generates a key quickly, either you've already interacted enough with the computer to provide enough entropy, or your computer has a supported hardware RNG.

Comment: Thanks Gilles. In my case though, use of gpg implies that 'dev/random' is being used, and a fresh install implies that dev/random has not had time to build up. So I still can't explain why the key generation consistently happens so quickly.

Comment: @SauceCode Maybe that machine has a hardware RNG? In that case, generating entropy is instantaneous by human standards. Does `/proc/cpuinfo` mention `rdrand`?

Comment: No, there is no rdrand. Moreover, I have used the same machine to do the same task on a regular install (not live CD) which takes much longer. That's what made me wonder in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

First, the difference between `/dev/urandom` and `/dev/random` is that `/dev/random` will block until there is enough entropy to generate a random number, whereas `/dev/urandom` doesn't block when entropy is exhausted. This also means that the generation on a `/dev/urandom` application can be less random than a number from `/dev/random`.

To your questions, the runtime for generating secrets varies based on the available entropy in the system and how lucky you are to get two primes quickly (without exhausting the entropy pool).

If you consistently get a keypair generated quickly on Tails, there is probably something wrong with the implementation.

Comment: I added the first paragraph as background for others that find this page later.

Comment: Thanks, I have just checked this a bit more and I do consistently get a keypair generated quickly.

Comment: I checked this on more than one machine. The .iso file I used had SHA256 checksum 587e06c70420e486fa441f872db5240fe24c3a4f7acb4f003fddaeb36d8c6df7, if anyone else would like to test the same.

Comment: Entropy is not exhausted. The only case in which `/dev/urandom` is insecure is on a new installation that does not have enough entropy yet (such as a live CD). After that, [`/dev/urandom` is just as secure as `/dev/random` except in a purely theoretical sense, and is perfectly suitable for a key generation](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key/3939#3939).